# Select Columns with Multiple Ranges from Excel using OleDb

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, oledb, excel-2003, oledbcommand

[image]
My current requirement is I need to select multiple ranges from an excel sheet(DUMMY.xls) in a single query and put it into a DataTable(fooData1) :
As you can see from the image above I have columns from A to F.
Therefore I am filtering out the columns from A to B and from D to F into a single dataTable(fooData1).
The content of the resulting datatable should be like:

```
NAME    ID     Date     Hobby     COLOR
DEEPAK  1               Coding    Black
ASTHA   2               Singing   Red
GAURAV  3               Dancing   Blue
BHAVESH 4     6/29/2007 Painting  Green
```

My Code goes like this:

and while executing the Query the following error fires up

> "Characters found after end of SQL statement."

```
     DataTable fooData1 = new DataTable();
                       System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection dbConnection =
              new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
                (@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
                 + @"Data Source=C:\Dummy.xls;"
                 + @"Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;""");
            dbConnection.Open();
            try
            {
                string strSql = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A:B] ; select * from[Sheet1$D:F]";
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql);
                cmd.Connection = dbConnection;
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter dbAdapter1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);                       
                dbAdapter1.Fill(fooData1);
                          }
            finally
            {
                dbConnection.Close();
            }
```

Comment: @evanc3: while executing the Query the following error fires up "Characters found after end of SQL statement."

Comment: Have you try it with one query? Just `SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A:B]`, because it looks like it won't accept querys which after semicolon.

Comment: @evanc3: As i have said I need to find data from multiple ranges.. and yes the query SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A:B] would work just fine !!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A:B],[Sheet1$E:F]` might works.

Comment: @evanc3: I have already tried that.. but it takes duplicates i.e. for every [Sheet1$A:B] it joins with every rows of [Sheet1$E:F]

Comment: How about `SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A:B,Sheet1$E:F]`? I tried in my Excel, it appears use `,` to separate selection.

Comment: no buddy its a syntax error :(

Answer (score 3):

It can be solve by SQL, use [`UNION ALL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx).

`SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A:B] UNION ALL select * from[Sheet1$E:F]`

I made test data like:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6
1   2   3   4   5   6
1   2   3   4   5   6
```

and the DataTable got:

```
1   2   
1   2   
5   6
5   6
```

(Since the option specific with `HDR=Yes`, the first row is header)

Hope that can solve your problem. :)

Comment: I have updated my question and i have made clear what i need now.

Comment: An alternative solution is process it in C#, like select all but do `fooData1.Columns.Remove("SALARY")`.

Comment: IS THE PROBLEM RESOLVED?

Answer (score 0):

Hey as for your question, you select individual columns by using the F and the column number. For example, "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A:B] ; select * from[Sheet1$D:F]"; could be re-write as:

```
"SELECT F1,F2,F4,F5 FROM [Sheet1$];"
```